# Java "missing return statement"

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors, return

Here is a small part of my code. The thing is that no matter what the code will go into that `if` statement.

```
public static double value(char[][] array, int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] == (char) 120) {
                    int x_cord = i;
                    int y_cord = j;
                    int width = (x_cord - x);
                    int height = (y_cord - y);
                    Math.abs(width);
                    Math.abs(height);
                    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
                    return distance;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that I have a logical flaw there somewhere and I need to tell the program somehow that it will get there no matter what but can i do that?

Comment: What if `array` is empty? You need to return something in that case. Or throw an exception.

Comment: You have to return from this method. Now you are returning only if the codition is true .

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will not accept methods with non-`void` return type, if it's not sure will

- return a value OR
- throw an exception

Since you are sure the `return` statement inside the loop is always executed, you can add a `return` statement with any value or throw a exception:

```
public static double value(char[][] array, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        ...
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("array must contain a char with code 120");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a `return` statement in every theoretically possible flow, even if there's no chance of getting there in runtime. Just add a "dummy return at the end, and you should be fine:

```
public static double value(char[][] array, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == (char) 120) {
                int x_cord = i;
                int y_cord = j;
                int width = (x_cord - x);
                int height = (y_cord - y);
                Math.abs(width);
                Math.abs(height);
                double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
                return distance;
            }

        }
    }

    return 0; // Or some other default
}
```

Comment: It should be noted, that by using this pattern special meaning is being assigned to the value 0.  In this case that might be appropriate but it can introduce subtle bugs, I don't feel it is very OO.  That said, given the information to hand I don't see any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a locale variable `double distance= 0;` initialized like this:

```
 public static double value(char[][] array, int x, int y) {
     double distance= 0;
    ...
       return distance;
        }
      }
    }
   return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible paths/branches through the code, each has to have a valid return statement if you have defined that your method returns a value.